# How can ı display image in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, server-side

My server url is something like `192.1.1.1:123` and my images folder in server is `F:\images\1234.jpg` but I published the website in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`

How can I refer to images from `F:`?

Comment: ~/ (Root-relative) & u can read about it here -https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using [virtual directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory)

```
   <application path="/files">
      <virtualDirectory path="/Images" physicalPath="F:\images" />
   </application>
```

then in browser accessing images from 192.1.1.1:123/files/images/1234.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Mode - 1

Read the image file in browser.

Implement this way in your code file.

```
ex.~/Content/images/img1.png
```

Mode - 2

After publish the code in this URL 192.1.1.1:123 then after follow the below step.

- Run URL in browser.
- Right click image and open in new tab then copy the URL. ex. //192.1.1.1:123/Content/images/img1.png
- Paste the URL in the code you need.

Comment: What mode did you try?